# Why does my drop down column menu only show 10 items

Tags: list

Still in development mode. I have a drop down menu column with 20 locations.  Only 10 show when I am accessing it.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Where are you using this drop down? Is this a specific web part, creating a list item, etc? Is the drop down menu another list or is this a choice column you have manually populated? What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint will render the drop down listing differently based on how many items are in the drop down menu. If there are more than X number of items you get a textbox / ajax / filtered type of list.

This is an older article but, helps explain how some scripting can resolve the issue for you.

http://sharepointegg.blogspot.com/2010/10/fixing-sharepoint-2010-lookup-drop-down.html